# How to rebuild SQL query, that will not return NULL

Tags: mysql

I have SQL query that gets rows by condition and outside query counts rows:

```
SELECT IdUserRecordstouser, SUM(IF(StatusRecordstouser IN('1', '0'), 1, 0)) AS NEW
FROM recordstouser
WHERE IdRecordstouser
IN (

SELECT IdRecordstouser
FROM recordstouser
WHERE IdtoUserRecordstouser =544
)
AND StatusRecordstouser = 1
```

Problem is that if `StatusRecordstouser = 0` I get NULL fields: `IdUserRecordstouser, NEW`, but I need to display rows in any case, because rows with `IdtoUserRecordstouser =544` exist but have `StatusRecordstouser = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `OR` in your filter if you want to choose those records that may have `StatusRecordtouser = 1` regardless of the `IdtoUserRercordstouser`? (Is that what you want to do?)

As written, your **subquery** will return a null set (`{NULL}`), or a singleton set (`{544}`) depending on whether the table recordstouser has that record with id = 544. The `AND` operator is then compounding that with whether `StatusRecordstouser = 0` and the result of `true AND false` is `false`.

As an aside, you should rename the columns to be more concise.

Comment: I need choose records for each `IdtoUserRercordstouser` groupped by `IdtoUserRercordstouser` and to count for each where `StatusRecordstouser = `1`